# scraping a webpage to get pdf links after a query

Tags: r, rvest

I am looking to scrape a website - https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.html which returns some pdf links after selecting a few drop downs. Here I'd like to select the dates and the category ("result") and get a list of pdf links which show in the result.

I am new to R and have tried multiple solutions using rvest presented here but none of them worked and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: "BSE is the owner of copyright in all information featured on this website and no portion of the information on this website may be reproduced on or transmitted to or stored in any other website or in other form of electronic retrieval system or by in any other form or by in any other means, without due permission from BSE Ltd." You are encouraged to ensure that your future requests for coding assistance are legal.

Answer (score -1):

All links are in the column `links`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w?pageno=1&strCat=-1&strPrevDate=20220809&strScrip=&strSearch=P&strToDate=20220809&strType=C" %>% 
  request() %>% 
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  .$Table %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  select(slongname, link = attachmentname, fld_attachsize , categoryname) %>% 
  mutate(link = link %>%  
           paste0("https://www.bseindia.com/xml-data/corpfiling/AttachLive/", .))

# A tibble: 50 × 4
   slongname                         link   fld_attachsize categoryname
   <chr>                             <chr>           <int> <chr>       
 1 Regent Enterprises Ltd            https…         782058 Result      
 2 A Infrastructure Ltd              https…        2474987 Company Upd…
 3 Delta Industrial Resources Ltd    https…       17649671 Company Upd…
 4 THERMAX LTD.                      https…         528774 Company Upd…
 5 MENON PISTONS LTD.                https…        3646522 Board Meeti…
 6 Shri Keshav Cements And Infra Ltd https…         386467 Company Upd…
 7 BETEX INDIA LTD.                  https…       19018100 Company Upd…
 8 MENON PISTONS LTD.                https…        3646522 Board Meeti…
 9 Delphi World Money Ltd            https…        8426244 Company Upd…
10 ESTER INDUSTRIES LTD.             https…         256407 Company Upd…
# … with 40 more rows
```